# Google Script, Delete files within a folder based on the last modified date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a script that will work through a shared drive once a week, and delete anything that has not been modified within the last 90 days.

I have found a few scripts on here that do not seem to work as I intended them to.

The script I currently have is below, but for some reason it does not seem to work, yet it seems as though it should.

It seems to identify the files, but does not seem to move them to the trash.

Any tips would be welcome thank you.

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var fileIDs = [];
  // Old date is 90 days
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*24*90;
  var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ClpJ8uwlVRc9zT4q2AsatEQBvPFTH5Eu');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
  });
};
```

Comment: The script works fine when I run it on my personal google drive.I think the script does not work because you are not the owner of the files or because you are doing this on a shared drive.

Comment: The code also works correctly for me, even with files that are shared they are also deleted (only from my account) and the folder remains empty. Can you give a little more context on your situation? Are you trying to delete your files from your account? Are any of them deleted? Have you checked that the folder id is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I was having a bad day, what I forgot to do is change the folder id from the test ID to the working ID