# Delete more than a month old back files from google drive using apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-drive-api

I am taking backup for sheets every week to back folder by doing below code. Now I want delete older filer more than 1 month to delete. how to add script which delete old files to from the backup folder.

**Backup code (trigger every week)**

```
function archiveCopy() {
    var file= DriveApp.getFileById("");
    var destination= DriveApp.getFolderById("");
    
    var timeZone=Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var formattedDate= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),timeZone,"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
    var name= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName()+"Copy"+formattedDate;
    
    
      file.makeCopy(name,destination);
      
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Script, Delete files within a folder based on the last modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060908/google-script-delete-files-within-a-folder-based-on-the-last-modified-date)

Comment: I thought that this thread might be your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74114388

Comment: Can I suggest that you go back and clean up (accept helpful answers) in your question history.

Answer (score 0):

Delete files one month old:

```
function deleteFilesOneMonthOld() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth() -1, dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("destinationfolderid");
  let ids = [];
  const files = folder.getFilesByType();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if(file.getDateCreated().valueOf() < dtv) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give you ten bucks if the OP actually accepts this correct and helpful answer.